# Why is $lim_{h\to 0} \frac{o(h)}{h} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is $$lim_{h\to 0} \frac{o(h)}{h} = 0$$

I mean if the function $o(h)$ means "some term in the order of $h^1$", then since $h\not = 0$, I can cancel each h in both denominator and enumerator, hence, I get a constant as the limit. However, in the Calculus books, such as Zorich's Mathematical Analysis book, he states that

[image]

So what am I missing in here ?

Comment: Because that's the definition of $o(h)...$ Perhaps you're thinking of big $O?$

Comment: Can you give a reference for the definition of $o(h)$ and $O(h)$. I couldn't find their formal definition anywhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $K = o(h)$ means ([by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)) that 
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h)}{h} = 0.$$

Added: I think the confusion comes from $h \to 0$. Let $x = 1/h$ and $g(x) = 1/x$. Then $o(h) = o(g(x))$. 
Thus if $f(x) = o(g(x))$, we have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/g(x) = 0$.
That is, 
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{o(h)}{h} &= 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{o(g(x))}{1/x} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{o(g(x))}{g(x)} = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: So informally, $o(h)$ might mean a term that is order lower than $h^1$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas _strictly_ lower

Comment: @onurcanbektas When you use $o(h)$-notation, you'd better to know how $h$ behaves. For example, if $h \to \infty$, $o(h)$ should be strictly lower  than $h$. If $h \to 0$, $o(h)$ should have strictly higher than $h$. But regardless where $h$ approach, $o(h)/h \to 0$ should hold.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.